# Php - Decode http response

Tags: php, json, http, decode

I need to decode the response of my request as an array

```
            $result = $this->sendHttpRequestFromHook($hook, $item);
            $customer = $result['response'];
            $customerDec = json_decode($customer, true);
```

$result contains an array of success,response and status and I have separated the response as $customer.Result of customer is as follows

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 13:01:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 656
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0b3005ad0a12f77a2c90d415299a67b81605099705; expires=Fri, 11-Dec-20 13:01:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.waveapps.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=UN0XCFMkT2N0J9s1zV8rT7DnX2602qwovF7WuI8dfGw7hQdd/m0sTpQKnj2LDQZHEt04qfdWCE4IdzHVUbf+3sYGPXAIXtXLlOYv3rfMyz+m0pdgp4ydwoCGztrR; Expires=Wed, 18 Nov 2020 13:01:45 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=UN0XCFMkT2N0J9s1zV8rT7DnX2602qwovF7WuI8dfGw7hQdd/m0sTpQKnj2LDQZHEt04qfdWCE4IdzHVUbf+3sYGPXAIXtXLlOYv3rfMyz+m0pdgp4ydwoCGztrR; Expires=Wed, 18 Nov 2020 13:01:45 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Client-Id: zUUT6X7oVQ.fV_DR.65QGl9X8aZluRjJVI1G-v-6
X-Wave-API-Version: 1
Vary: Origin, Cookie
Expires: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 13:01:44 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0658feeaea00007f1181a8b000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5f083424adcb7f11-CMB

{"id":46437620,"url":"https://api.waveapps.com/businesses/customers/46437620/","account_number":"","active":true,"name":"ddddd xxxxx","first_name":"","last_name":"","email":"ttttt@t.lk","fax_number":"","mobile_number":"","phone_number":"","toll_free_number":"","website":"","internal_notes":"","currency":{"url":"https://api.waveapps.com/currencies/SGD/","code":"SGD","symbol":"$","name":"Singapore dollar","plural":null},"address1":"","address2":"","city":"","province":null,"country":null,"postal_code":"","date_created":"2020-11-11T13:01:45+00:00","date_modified":"2020-11-11T13:01:45+00:00","shipping_details":null}
```

I need to get the id of the above result.Please help

Got the following result in my terminal for var_dump($customer)

```
string(1910) "HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:12:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 659
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4340d399a0ff44e41c51062a9baca52f1605107542; expires=Fri, 11-Dec-20 15:12:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.waveapps.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=4BtBF6k5ldc1RuDHRZP1CXNqi4dGJk2pyO5LLeZSwiLU12A0k9Ah71KZtGSCjgQpQmhVAbPPuYbxt72kgOJ8+Jt5asPIYBziSz+ru8yKxz8fO73rVpcwzVNerxoh; Expires=Wed, 18 Nov 2020 15:12:22 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBC"...
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You have a response, you've decoded it. Where is the code that tries to get the id but fails?

Comment: $customerDec get the result as null

Comment: Wait, when you say "Result of customer is as follows", is that an actual dump of the `$customer` variable?

Comment: yes that is the http response I got for $result which I got separated as $customer

Comment: Where did you get all this information from? The developer toolbar or from an actual `var_dump` call?

Comment: evaluated with php storm

Comment: I'm not using PHPStorm so I don't know how it retrieves the data. Can you do a proper `var_dump` and see what the result is?

Comment: does it matters?because its the response I get for my http request

Comment: _"does it matters?"_ - What your variable contains _absolutely_ matters since you ask us how to extract data from it. What you've posted looks like both the response headers and the response body. You only want to get data from the response body so it's very important for us to know if your `$result` variable contains just a json string or the headers as well. If it contains the headers as well, then you can't use `json_decode()` on it. You then must parse out the body part (the json string) and decode just that.

Comment: the result for $customer is the response of a curl request.How can I parse out the body part?

Comment: cURL doesn't return the headers and the body together like that. Can you please do as others have asked you to? Do a `var_dump($customer);` and add that output to the question. If not, I can't help you since I don't use PHP storm and don't know what that output actually is (which makes it useless for me and others that don't know PHP storm).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have added

Comment: Can you post your cURL code as well? Are you fetching the data from some external API or do you call some API that's owned by you? What do you get if you make a request to that AP using Postman or similar? Do you get all those headers together with the body as well?

Comment: I'm using an extension called webhook to sync with an app called waveapp.So the request is sent by the extension.When I use postman I get the customer details only.

Comment: Is it [this](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-webhook/tree/master) extension?

Comment: I wrote my own curl request instead of using the request in the extension and I got the json response correctly.